# Coming soon page in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm developing a website but want a "Coming soon" page to be up for now. How do I structure a "Coming soon" page in my rails app 3.1? What's the best way to go about doing it.

Four options I'm considering are:

1. Have a static coming soon page in the public directory. Have rails routes point to it and then modify my routes file when I go live.
2. Have a page served by a controller pointing to www.myproject.com/home. I'll just change the routes file when I'm ready to go live to www.myproject.com
3. Use LaunchRock.com. Have my domain posted to LaunchRock and then point it to my site when I'm ready.
4. Use https://github.com/vinsol/Launching-Soon/

Which method is best suited for my Rails project?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of these have different pros and cons. It's up to you really.

If you're close to launch, you'll have to set up a web-server and Rails anyhow, so either setting up a Rails controller for serving the static pages, or have a static page in your public directory, are probably the best choices then.

Personally I'd not serve the "coming soon" page through other sites/services. 
One reason for having some sort of "coming soon" page is for SEO purposes. For that it's best to have full control over your site / page.

I'd go for using a Controller for the static pages, because you can more easily use the same layout as your site, and you can add dynamic content to that page (e.g. a sign-up or a contact form).

See:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages

Option number 6) serve the static page through Rack

http://railscasts.com/episodes/222-rack-in-rails-3

Comment: I'll go with using a controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the above, and one more:

5.Have you webserver return a static page for all requests, bypassing rails completely.

Which one you use depends on how much trouble you want to go to, and whether you want some sort of basic app functionality (like announcements).

I suggest you make a list of what features you actually need, or are sure you'll use, and see how that matches with your list.

One thing to take into account is the time-frame. If the 'launching soon' is not going to be that soon then you'll want some way to easily keep people informed.

Comment: +1 for adding option number 5) :-)  

e.g. if you have Nginx or Apache in front of Rails, you can serve the static pages directly through them, completely bypassing Rails.

Comment: just wanted to clarify that for the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

Put a static page with some copy up *today* for SEO purposes.  Then consider your marketing objectives and think about what kind of features you need (e.g. mailing list signup, window into application data, viral video, etc).  Balance the needs of those features against time taken away from actual development.

At the end you ask the right question (emphasis mine):

> Which method is best suited for **my** Rails project?

But you don't give any context.  Any of the methods you mentioned could be appropriate, but they are meaningless without understanding the business goals.  A technical forum such as this is probably not the best place to ask at this stage.